# How can I erase the old data from logcat?

Tags: android, android-emulator, logcat

When I execute the command

`adb logcat`

while running the android emulator, all of the old logs blow past and so I figure they are stored in a file somewhere. Is there a command I can run to clear the logs and start fresh? If not, is there some other way to do this?

Comment: Instead of clearing the log - just apply the timestamp filter https://stackoverflow.com/q/45416946/1778421

Answer (score 140, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
 adb logcat -c
```

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html

Comment: For some reason that didn't clear the log for me when passing `-s` flag for specific device.

Answer (score 20):

```
adb logcat -c
```

didn't do it for me

```
adb logcat -b all -c
```

worked

Comment: This should be the correct answer. If you are analysing SELinux, the other answer won't work.

Answer (score 5):

Dup of 
[How to empty (clear) the logcat buffer in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3315389/how-to-empty-clear-the-logcat-buffer-in-android/47686978#47686978)

The following command will clear only non-rooted buffers (main, system ..etc).

```
adb logcat -c
```

If you want to clear all the buffers (like radio, kernel..etc), Please use the following commands

```
adb logcat -b all -c
```

or

```
adb root
adb shell logcat -b all -c
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, **adb logcat -c** was not working and was giving following error :

```
failed to clear the 'main' log
```

For this, I first did :

```
adb shell
```

Than I did :

```
logcat -c
```

then exit the shell.
This way I was able to clear logcat when same was not getting cleared from adb logcat -c