# How to empty the logcat buffer in Android Code

Tags: android, permissions, logcat

When I show the LogCat in Android, I want to clear the buffer Log programmatically.
But when I use this statement:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -c")
```

It doesn't clear the buffer.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You can check herer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3315389/how-to-empty-the-logcat-buffer-in-android

Comment: I want clear logcat in Code , by statement not by ADB . Can you give me other idea?

Comment: This will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27678829/android-clear-log-programmatically

Comment: thank you for your help . But it still had problem . I think I lack in permission to clear Log . My Device is SamSung Note 4 . OS : 4.4.4

Comment: Then add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />` to your manifest

Comment: `READ_LOGS` is no longer granted to apps since Jelly Bean

Comment: i am also trying to clear my logcat buffer through code, But its not working from code. Any idea ?

Comment: I recently faced this issue. Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -c") was working on some devices & failed on few. After a lot of research...my conclusion is        It is Android Operating System dependent process, which shows different behaviours for few Android API Levels (API 16 to API 21)
 The Logcat command "logcat -c" is deprecated for API 16 to API 21, as this command clears the whole systems

Comment: Instead of clearing the log - just apply the timestamp filter https://stackoverflow.com/q/45416946/1778421

Answer (score 1):

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -c")`  will clear only non-rooted log buffers (main, system ..etc).
Please use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -b all -c")` to clear all the buffers (like radio, kernel..etc)

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced this issue. Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -c") was working on some devices & failed on few. After a lot of research...my conclusion is

1. It is Android Operating System dependent process, which shows
   different behaviours for few Android API Levels (API 16 to API 21)
2. The Logcat command "logcat -c" is deprecated for API 16 to API 21,
   as this command clears the whole systems Logs

Instead of depending on Logcat process and writing logs to Logcat, create one custom file in app context (/data/data//files) and write all logs to this file.