# Can a specified message or row be cleared in the adb logcat instead of clearing all?

Tags: android, adb, logcat, monkeyrunner

I am using Monkeyrunner (automation) to test an app on an Android device (Samsung S2), and since it does not allow me to see image patterns on the screen, I have to rely on the adb logcat (using Windows) to look for specific messages in order to know when the next page has loaded for my automation script.

And in order to look for specific (unique) messages in the logcat, for my monkeyrunner script, I have to CLEAR out ALL the adb logs, then perform the search.

Is there a way to clear out only the line(s) that match a specific tag, message, text, or whatever(!), within the logcat log? Instead of clearing out everything?

Does the command line adb functionality allow you to clear specific lines, or is it an all or nothing kinda thing?

Clearing out all the logcat longs works, but it would be nice to ONLY clear out certain messages so that if/when there is an app crash, or some event where I need details for troubleshooting, I can see all the logs leading up to the crash (or significant event). Because if everything is cleared out, there is no way for me to see the logcat logs to troubleshoot whatever.

::: MORE INFORMATION :::

Here is the function I currently use to clear out all the logs.

```
def clearAdb():
    p = subprocess.Popen("adb logcat -v time", shell=True, cwd="C:\Users\<USERNAME>AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    subprocess.Popen("adb logcat -c", shell=True, cwd="C:\Users\<USERNAME>AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    print("::: ADB cleared :::")
```

..and here's an example of how I am looking for the logcat log. This adb function waits indefinitely for a specific adb message, and process when seen.

```
def adb(message):
    p = subprocess.Popen("adb logcat -v time", shell=True, cwd="C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    for line in p.stdout:
        if message in line:
            print("Got 'em")
            break
        else:
            continue
```

...and this is how I currently use the functions together...

```
clearAdb()
adb("identifyGamePackage. com.tfg.nameofapplication")
```

Comment: why exactly do you think that you *need* to clear the log at all?

Comment: Because there is a lot of looping in my automation scripts, and I have to reuse the same logcat messages several times, and if the previously used message is not cleared by the time I start looking for it again, my script will incorrectly find the first time the logcat message appeared, and prematurely move on to the next action.

Comment: so change your script to find the proper instance of the message. you do not need to clear the log to do that

Comment: I'm assuming, when you say "proper instance", not the old instance but the new one.  Here's an example of the initial message, then a new one....how should I look for the new that hasnt happened yet?  (...)
07-31 13:26:01.211 V/WindowStateAnimator( 1259): Finishing drawing window Window{87f82e9 u0 d0 com.tfg.myApplication/com.tfg.myApplication.activities.home.SplashScreen}: mDrawState=HAS_DRAWN
  (...)
07-31 13:30:01.211 V/WindowStateAnimator( 1259): Finishing drawing window Window{87f82e9 u0 d0 com.tfg.myApplication/com.tfg.myApplication.activities.home.SplashScreen}: mDrawState=HAS_DRAWN

Comment: instead of clearing the log - just get the current timestamp. then use logcat time filter to filter all prior messages

Comment: I guess I'm not sure how to interact with timestamps using adb. Do you know how I could add in the current timestamps (so I can filter out everything before the current datetime)? Perhaps we could use my "adb(message)" function as an example?

Comment: Perhaps you are trying to solve the wrong problem. Why don't you just ask about your original problem (detecting patterns and images on the device screen). Hint, [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) could be of great help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To limit `logcat` output to messages which happened after certain moment you do not have to clear the log. Instead use `logcat -T <timestamp>` filter. Supported *timestamp* formats depend on the Android version - see `-T` paragraph in `logcat -h` output.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you are talking about?

Comment: I did this "adb shell echo $EPOCHREALTIME" on one line, and then right after I do this "adb logcat -T $EPOCHREALTIME" but I get the following error message: "$EPOCHREALTIME" not in "%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%q" time format. Not only does this command NOT set a specific datetime, but is is also in the wrong format. Can you please expand just a little further?

Comment: The error message is very clear. Your device is quite old and it does not support logcat timestamps in epoch format. So use the format it does support.

Comment: I get the same error message even if I give it a fixed time... like ...adb logcat -T '08-01 13:10:10.222'

Comment: Alex, your suggestion was correct, I needed to use "-t", and it worked. But i didn't need to specify a time. Here's what my variable looked like......p = Popen("adb logcat shell -t", shell=True, cwd="C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools", stdout=PIPE). When I used this, it simply knew to pick up where it last left off in the corresponding function loop. Also, this "p" variable needs to be NOT in the function, but declared globally. Thanks Alex!

Comment: @JordanViaComputer, The way to say "Thanks" at StackOverflow is by *upvoting* (and *accepting* if you can do so) useful answers.