# Adb Logcat to print only live traces

Tags: adb, android-logcat

I am using following command which prints android device logs from connected device buffer in my desktop.

```
adb logcat
```

Now requirement is, i am running a test and want to see the output of current action in logs.

That is i need logs only since when i start logging command.

i don't want logs from the buffer or the logs prior to time when logging is started.

Also i don't want to clear the buffer using -c argument. because somebody (some other process) may need buffered traces during testing

```
adb logcat --live-trace
```

*Thanks in advance for the help.*

Comment: i forgot to add one thing. i don't want to clear the buffer using -c argument. because somebody (some other process) may need buffered traces during testing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45422595/1778421

Comment: adb logcat -t <timestamp> sounds helpful. but device is having different time other than my test pc. is there any way we can fetch current time and use same timestamp into logcat? i am exploring. meanwhile can some one help me? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i found the perfect way to do it!

Read current time from the device only.

```
adb shell echo $(date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Merge the above output with ".000" (just adding milliseconds) and save into some variable say %timestamp%.
Then,

```
adb logcat -v threadtime - D -T %timestamp%
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use it in one command:

```
adb logcat -v threadtime - D -T $(adb shell echo $(date +'%s')).000
```

Answer (score 1):

From logcat's help:

```
-d                          Dump the log and then exit (don't block).
-T <count>                  Print only the most recent <count> lines (does not imply -d).
```

This would print a line and keep printing:

`adb logcat -T 1`

(Tested on Android version 12, may not work on older Android versions)